# Any good calendar app in Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, calendar

I'm trying to find a **calendar app** that works with the **Xfce desktop**.
I do not want to use a gnome-based calendar, as I do not want to have the heavy gnome programs to run in the background, as my ram is very limited.
I also want it to be **synchronised** **with** **google calendar**, which I use on my phone.

All that google proposes me is that old "*orage*" calendar app for Xfce from 2010.

Any help ? Shall I give up ?

Comment: Are you using Thunderbird? You can use its calendar.

Comment: Alternatively, since you’re using Google Calendar, there’s always the browser … 

Comment: You've not said which release, but modern Xfce uses the same libraries/toolkit (GTK3) as GNOME does, so what really is your concern?  Xfce hasn't been GTK2 for some time now  (*are you using a supported release*?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try GNOME Calendar.

```
sudo apt install gnome-calendar gnome-online-accounts
```

You can sign in to your Google account in GNOME online accounts, and sync it with Google Calendar.

[image]
 <sup>Image source: https://apps.gnome.org/app/org.gnome.Calendar/</sup>

It does not run other GNOME apps in the background, and consumes <100 MB memory, and is not very heavy.

[image: resources consumption]

Comment: Thanks, works exactly as I want !